# I am using node js with mongodb got authentication error when to connect 'MongoError: Authentication failed'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I'm getting the following error

> MongoError: Authentication failed.

After 15-20 days after to create admin user.

I am using this query to create admin user for db.

```
use sampleDb

db.createUser({
    user: "unhuDevAdmin",
    pwd: "devpass123",
    roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]}
);
```

`sampleDB` is my db name.

Mongo db version: v3.4.4

At the time of creating of this user i can access my db and after 15-20 days got authentication error and lost my all data from db. I don't know why this happening again and again.

Comment: simply `dbAdmin` role doesn't work?

Comment: Please include query which you used to add user

Comment: this is my query
use sampleDb

db.createUser(
{ user: "unhuDevAdmin", pwd: "devpass123", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] } );

Answer (score 1):

Here is the chunk from [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/add-user-administrator/):

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "siteUserAdmin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: Your query seems similar to the asked question except the role. However main problem is the created user with above query is showing as unauthorised user after 15-20 days. I am also facing the same issue. Please assist..

Comment: I think the role here is the key. Also it's very wierd, that OP has both readWrite and dbAdmin. I don't see role dbAdmin at all in the docs.